Managed Identity on Databricks - DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials
I am trying to send a message to a service bus in azure.
But I get following error:
 ServiceBusError: Handler failed: DefaultAzureCredential failed to
 retrieve a token from the included credentials.

This is the line that fails:
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

Normally, I would use the az login, but not sure how to do this in databricks.
import nest_asyncio
import asyncio
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusMessage
from azure.servicebus.aio import ServiceBusClient

from azure.identity.aio import DefaultAzureCredential

nest_asyncio.apply()

local_user = dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().userName().get()

print(local_user)

FULLY_QUALIFIED_NAMESPACE = "xxx.servicebus.windows.net"
TOPIC_NAME = "xxoutbound"

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
token = credential.get_token('xxx')
print(token)

async def send_single_message(sender):
    # Create a Service Bus message and send it to the queue
    message = ServiceBusMessage("Single Message")
    await sender.send_messages(message)
    print("Sent a single message")

async def run():
    # create a Service Bus client using the credential
    async with ServiceBusClient(
        fully_qualified_namespace=FULLY_QUALIFIED_NAMESPACE,
        credential=credential,
        logging_enable=True) as servicebus_client:
        # get a Queue Sender object to send messages to the queue
        sender = servicebus_client.get_topic_sender(topic_name=TOPIC_NAME)
        async with sender:
            # send one message
            await send_single_message(sender)

        # Close credential when no longer needed.
        await credential.close()

print("dfsdf")

asyncio.run(run())
print("Done sending messages")
print("-----------------------")


You no need to retrieve token, you can just pass the credential to client and send the message.
When you use default credential it takes managed identity as the authorization credential. So, you need to give Azure Service Bus Data Sender role to the identity.

You can see the identity resource in your databricks managed resource group.
Output:
In dbx

and in service bus queue


Thanks, highly appreciated. So in short the code is correct, but its the authentication to the service bus. I will test it out and get back. Highly appreciated.

You no need to get the token. Automatically it takes when you create service bus client.
